# Why could Web Service call be slower than a web POST request

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, web-applications

I have a .NET web service hosted in IIS. The web service has been used by clients over the past few years and there has been occassional timeout events when the client is on a slow connection (e.g. GPRS). On the other hand the clients sometimes have to POST some data to another web page (part of an ASP.NET web app) and usually the size of the data in the POST requests is bigger than the actual payloads in the web service calls. However the POST requests are far quicker as compared to the web service calls.

To establish this further I created a test web service with one method and another single web page with exactly the same operation i.e. receive 100K and send back 100K (random bytes) and I used a test client to call the web service method as well as did a post to the web page and got a response back using the same client. The difference in receiving a reply back from the web service and a response back from the web post request is huge i.e. about 1200 ms. Why is that the case? Is there any such configuration on the web service that would make such a big difference? Is it SOAP call stack? Serialization/Desrialization?

Answer (score 0):

A number of factors could be contributing to this.

The first thing that leaps to mind for me is that SOAP could be considered a verbose protocol. That is, there's a LOT of data in the XML payload going both ways. XML is verbose in and of itself, and it's not exactly the fastest thing in the universe to process. Sure, you can use an optimized library to process it's data, but it'll be parsed out into object trees, then you can walk the nodes to drill down to the data you want. Unless you're using XPath, which will just do the same darned thing.

This is all presuming that you're actually using SOAP. And that your WebService is correctly configured. And that no packet loss is occurring while connecting to the Web Service. And that your firewall isn't creating issues. And that there's no encryption/decryption overhead.

In my own experience, one thing that frequently causes signficant slowdowns server side is one or more thrown exceptions. Try a [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) trace.

Comment: ok SOAP/XML could be one factor and we are talking about more data being transported and the overhead of parsing may be but i still don't think it should have such a big impact .. the other 2 factors do not exist in my test app at least i.e. encryption and exceptions (application level) .. I shall try Fidler though .. also not sure what configuration options could be contributing to the problem ... thanks

Comment: How big are your packets? And, I found this document, which is fairly old, but might help you out from a research perspective: http://nsfcac.rutgers.edu/TASSL/Papers/p2p-p2pws02-soap.pdf